# Not able to execute batch file in php

Tags: php, windows, apache, batch-file, wamp

I m trying to execute batch file in php file. I m using Apache server. Itried following ways but its not working

PHP Code

```
echo shell_exec('download.bat');
echo exec('download.bat'); 
system ("cmd /c download.bat");//Also tried for exec and shell_exec
```

Batch file contains downloading code using ftp client

Batch file

```
"c:\program files\coreftp\coreftp.exe" -s -O    -site mysite   -d /Export/*.*   -p C:\wamp\www\file\txt
```

If I run it in cmd or run directly then its works fine when I run its in php its just write or echo batch file's code

download.bat file is in same folder.

I also tried to call simple bat file

```
start "link" "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=NzuIVI-FG6aG8Qef44CAAw"
```

Its also not calling to this bat file

Comment: How exactly is it _not working_

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your 'download.bat' file is in the same PATH as your PHP script?

Try to use absolute path like this

```
exec('C:\\MY\\PATH\\TO\\download.bat');
```

Comment: Yes its in same folder and I tried this but not working?

Comment: Try to run an other bat which only do an 'ECHO' to be sure if it come from your bat or your php script

Answer (score 0):

Just use `exec('download.bat');` if the file is in the same directory, however you need to ensure that Apache has correct permissions to execute the batch file i.e. it should be running on an Administrator account. If you're on Win7 or above, look at how to run programs in elevated mode.

Comment: How to check apache has correct permission or not ?Its running on  administrator account.

Comment: Go to Start>Run>Services.msc and in the services list look for 'Apache Service' and check that it is being run under an account that has admin privileges.

Comment: Yes its has admin privileges

Comment: try something like `$test = exec('download.bat', $rVal);` `echo var_dump($test) . "\n\n";` `echo var_dump($rVal);`

Comment: I tried this and its echo the output and its type is string.its not generate the output

Comment: I'm not sure you can use `"c:\program files\coreftp\coreftp.exe"` in your batch file, because it's being run from server side, and that wouldn't be a valid path relative to the server. When you run it from CMD or directly, you are running it on your local machine which is why that naming convention would work.